# LLDB Doesn't Understand Single Dash Character?

Tags: swift, lldb

I'm having trouble reading through the characters in a string, wherein, the string contains a dash. Once I attempt to convert that dash `Character` to a `String`, the debugger can no longer read the data. What is happening here? Can lldb not read single dash characters?

[image]

There are a couple ways you can try this.

1. Fire up any app and type the command in lldb `p String("-")` we're basically trying to get swift to convert a char to a string and it shows "unable to read data".
2. Take any string with a dash and attempt to map its chars to strings, like this `"mystring-withadash.characters.map({ String($0) })`. You'll get the output as below.

[image]

Comment: Please post the actual code you are trying to run, rather than screenshots.

Comment: @AshleyMills my post includes actual code you can use to try it out. if something needs to be clarified, let me know. otherwise one could simply take #1 or #2 in any app and put it in `print()`

Comment: I can reproduce the issue, but it seems  "only" to be a problem of lldb or the debugger console. What do you mean by *"my app blows up"* ? Is there any problem with running your code?

Comment: @MartinR removing that line. after debugging and looking more closely, the blowing up part is a consequence of my code, not the debugger

Comment: @MartinR looks like swift doesn't really have a problem with this, it's actually just LLDB being incapable of reading it for some reason. Is it bad form to change the title of post to be more accurate?

Comment: There is already a similar bug report: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3564: You get the same error with `p "OK"` in the debugger console.